# I can't compile class with an interface

Tags: delphi, interface

I am trying to create a class that implements an interface but I get these errors:

```
[dcc32 Error] dl_tPA_MailJournal.pas(10): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IInterface.QueryInterface
[dcc32 Error] dl_tPA_MailJournal.pas(10): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IInterface._AddRef
[dcc32 Error] dl_tPA_MailJournal.pas(10): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IInterface._Release
[dcc32 Fatal Error] MainUnit.pas(8): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'dl_tPA_MailJournal.pas'
```

The code is:

```
unit dl_tPA_MailJournal;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Generics.Collections,
  SysUtils,
  uInterfaces;

type
  TtPA_MailJournal = class(TObject, ITable)
  public
    function GetanQId: integer;
    procedure SetanQId(const Value: integer);
    function GetadDate: TDateTime;
    procedure SetadDate(const Value: TDateTime);

    function toList: TList<string>;

    constructor Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);

  private
    property anQId : integer read GetanQId write SetanQId;
    property adDate : TDateTime read GetadDate write SetadDate;
end;

implementation

{ TtPA_MailJournal }

constructor TtPA_MailJournal.Create(aId : Integer; aDate : TDateTime);
begin
  SetanQId(aId);
  SetadDate(aDate);
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.GetadDate: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := adDate;
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.GetanQId: integer;
begin
  Result := anQId ;
end;

procedure TtPA_MailJournal.SetadDate(const Value: TDateTime);
begin
  adDate := Value;
end;

procedure TtPA_MailJournal.SetanQId(const Value: integer);
begin
  anQId := Value;
end;

function TtPA_MailJournal.toList: TList<string>;
var
  aListTable: TList<TtPA_MailJournal>;
  aTable: TtPA_MailJournal;
  aListString: TList<String>;
begin
  aTable.Create(1,now);
  aListTable.Add(aTable);
  aTable.Create(2,now);
  aListTable.Add(aTable);
  aListString.Add(aListTable.ToString);

  Result := aListString;
end;

end.
```

And the interface is:

```
unit uInterfaces;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections;

type
  ITable = Interface
    ['{6CED8DCE-9CC7-491F-8D93-996BE8E4D388}']
    function toList: TList<string>;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you use `TObject` as the parent for your class.  You should use [`TInterfacedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TInterfacedObject) instead.

In Delphi, every interface inherits from `IInterface` at therefore has, at least, the following [3 methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.IInterface_Methods):

- [_AddRef](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TInterfacedObject._AddRef)
- [_Release](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TInterfacedObject._Release)
- [QueryInterface](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TInterfacedObject.QueryInterface)

You must implement these 3 methods, either by implementing them yourself or by inheriting from a base object that includes these methods.

Because you inherit from `TObject`, but you are not implementing these 3 methods, you get a compilation error.  If you read the compiler error, you will see that it actually spells out this omission for you.

[`TInterfacedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TInterfacedObject) has already implemented these methods for you.
*Other base objects that implement [`IInterface` (aka `IUnknown`)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/The_Fundamental_COM_Interface,_IUnknown) are: [`TAggregatedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TAggregatedObject) and [`TContainedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TContainedObject). However these are special purpose vehicles, only to be used if you really know what you're doing.*

Change the definition of your class to

```
TTPA_MailJournal = class(TInterfacedObject, ITable)
```

And your code will compile.

See [Delphi basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Interface) for more info.

Comment: Or, depending on where it is used, one can [also use TAggregatedObject or TContainedObject](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30125).